# Node JS, how to store the result in session?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

[Here is the complete image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RFjP5.png)

I need the result to Store in session. Is that easly Possible?

This is My Route,

```
app.get('/employ',(req,res) =>{

var q="select * from employee"
connection.query(q,(err,result) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("fetched values successfully...");
})

console.log(result);

res.render("addemploy.hbs")
})
```

If yes, mention how to access stored values from session anytime.

Comment: I tried, now data is Null.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: @mrobbizulfikar How would that help? the data would still be null the millisecond after the query statement was executed but before it had finished. That is the point/problem with async

Answer (score 2):

You are using `results` out of the scope block (query), move the `console.log(results)` inside the scope of `connection.query`. If you wish to use the results in your template as well, render the page inside the scope as well. Make sure to render another page in case of an error in your query.

```js
app.get('/employ',(req,res) =>{
    const q = "select * from employee";
    connection.query(q,(err,result) => {
        if (err) return res.send(err);
        console.log("fetched values successfully...");
        console.log(result);

        res.render("addemploy.hbs", { data: result });
    });
});
```

Comment: @Sankar Glad it worked for you! Feel free to accept the answer if you like :)